Vuejs access to file outside of the application
I have several files on my server located at /var/www/files/
My vuejs is in ~/Dev/app
I did : let file = require('/var/www/files/myfile.jpg')
then npm run build my app.
But I have this error  :
Error: Cannot find module '/var/www/files/myfile.jpg'

I can access my files when they are in ~/Dev/app/public/ tho 
To add a bit more clarity : I want my user to download a file from my server to its web browser. I can do that when the file is in the project /public but not when it's somewhere else on the server.

Consider explaining your case, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . It's unknown what's your setup, while it's relevant. Generally you have all the files that you import inside the project. Why are they located at /var/www/files/ ? In case you need them in both places, use fs links

I can't move from where they are but I need to access them. I wish I could have done things my way but this is how the legacy code I'm working on works.

As I said, you can create a link to make files available inside project hierarchy

You need to provide it on a public url, or to handle it via an intermediary.
